# SharePoint 2013 user can only access files and values entered into custom list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

In my first SharePoint 2013 project, I want to create a view where users can only see their own files that they generated. I think I know how to create this view when the list is associated with the 'Documents; folder. However I have created several custom lists where I can only see these items when I am on the navigation pane to the left and the unique custom lists are listed under 'recent'.

I want users to only see lists and files that they created in both the documents library and in mainly in the custom list files the user created.

The custom list files I am referring are created in the following manner:

1. A SharePoint 2013 site is opened in the web browser like internet explorer,
2. click on Add lists, libraries, and other apps on this page,
3. You are on the site contents--> Your Apps page and you then click on 'custom list'.
4. You then give the custom list a name, add columns to the list by clicking on 'edit this list'. You then click on stop editing.
5. You then click on +new  item and add values to the list and click the save button.

You can normally find the custom lists in the navigation pane to the left side under recent and you can find all the custom lists that have been created.

Thus can you tell me how to allow users to see only:

1. The data they entered into custom lists and
2. Whatever they entered into the document library?

Answer (score 1):

Lists are easy, go into the List Settings and click on Advanced Settings. In the Item Level Permissions settings, set the Read option to "Read items that were created by the user" and in the create and edit section set it to "Create and edit items that were created by the user."

Document libraries do not have this setting however. You can simulate it by creating a view and setting a filter where the Created By field is equal to [Me] and set this as the default view. This will show a filtered view of all the documents where the current user created them. This isn't true security though, if the documents are sensitive this wouldn't work.